# Best environment for interactive installation?

Tags: python, pi-4, software-recommendation

I'm gathering some hardware for a permanent interactive wall installation that will utilise Pi 4 and some touch sensors via GPIO. The Pi will be hooked up to a video projector and a speaker. The idea is to display some information and trivia in a loop and interrupt with a sound or a video when touch button is pressed. Ideally, I'd like for the information to be animated, including typography and graphic elements, so it looks more refined.

I planned to code it in Python but maybe there's a better solution like a specialised software for such things that I missed on the Pi? Thanks for any pointers.